# What is the julia equivalent of np.indices in numpy?

Tags: julia

In Python, there is [np.indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html#numpy-indices), which returns the indices of a grid:

```
Python 2.7.1
> import numpy as np
> x,y = np.indices((2,2))
> x
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
> y
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

What would be a similar function in Julia? Especially for multidimensional grids.

I tried `eachindex`, but it expects a grid as input, not just the dimensions. Also the output is a flat list of linear indices, instead of separated cartesian components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be obtained using the `CartesianIndices` function:

```
julia> inds = CartesianIndices((2,2))
2×2 CartesianIndices{2,Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64},Base.OneTo{Int64}}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1)  CartesianIndex(1, 2)
 CartesianIndex(2, 1)  CartesianIndex(2, 2)

julia> Tuple.(inds)
2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64},2}:
 (1, 1)  (1, 2)
 (2, 1)  (2, 2)

julia> getindex.(inds, 1)
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 2  2

julia> getindex.(inds, 2)
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 1  2
```

Comment: As an additional note observe that you can use entries of the above `inds` array directly to index an array of a given dimension. If you prefer linear indices to Cartesian indices you can use `LinearIndices` function.